# change position of caption with margincap

Tags: captions, margins, marginpar

[image]

Currently it looks like that but i want the caption to be aligned with the top of the image and not the bottom.

My Tex file looks like this:

```
\documentclass
  [
    captions=topbeside,
    oneside, DIV=12, 11pt, ngerman
  ]
  {scrreprt}


\marginparwidth=2.5cm
\textwidth=12.5cm
\hoffset = 0cm
\voffset = 2cm
\textheight = 20.5cm
\headsep = 1cm
\footskip = 2cm
\marginparsep = -15.2cm
\oddsidemargin = 3.36cm
\evensidemargin = 3.36cm

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Frutiger LT 45 Light}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\rmfamily}

\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Large}
\addtokomafont{section}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{subsection}{\normalsize}
\addtokomafont{subsubsection}{\normalsize}





\usepackage{mcaption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}

\renewcommand{\cftdot}{}

\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[automark]{scrpage2}
\clearscrheadfoot
\rofoot[\pagemark]{\pagemark}
\cfoot[\tiny Entwicklung und Evaluierung einer modularen Laseroptik für die \\ \hspace{2.35cm} Bearbeitungswellenlänge von 450 nm]{\tiny Entwicklung und Evaluierung einer modularen Laseroptik für die \\ \hspace{2.35cm} Bearbeitungswellenlänge von 450 nm }
\lehead{\leftmark}
\rohead{\leftmark}


\usepackage{romanbarpagenumber}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize]{caption}
\captionsetup{format=plain}
\captionsetup[figure]{name={Bild}}
\captionsetup[margincap]{indention=0pt,justification=RaggedLeft}


%\usepackage{showframe}% shows the page layout


\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=debug]{biblatex}
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelalpha}{\thefield{entrykey}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{extraalpha}{}
\bibliography{Quellenverzeichnis/Quellen-MA.bib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{}
%\usepackage{cite}

\usepackage{header}

\def\table{\def\figurename{Tabelle}\figure}
\let\endtable\endfigure 

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{placeins}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{diagbox}
\usepackage{pdfpages}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{units}
%\usepackage{siunitx}

\newcommand\bootstrapsamples{N_\text P}
\newcommand\gausswidth{\sigma}
\newcommand\initialrandomwidth{\tilde \Delta}
\newcommand\iterations{M}
\newcommand\iterationsbetween{M_\text{Zw}}
\newcommand\margin{\Delta}
\newcommand\mass{\mu}
\newcommand\preiterations{M'}
\newcommand\rounds{\bar n}
\newcommand\timesites{N}
\newcommand\timestep{a}

\begin{document}

\includepdf[pages={1-2}, fitpaper=true]{Deckblatt.pdf}

\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.7cm}{0pt}
    \tableofcontents
\end{adjustwidth}

\pagenumbering{Roman}

\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.7cm}{0pt}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listfigurename}
    \listoffigures
\end{adjustwidth}



\begin{adjustwidth}{-2.7cm}{0pt}
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listtablename}
    \listoftables
\end{adjustwidth}

\newpage

    \begin{figure}[hbt]
    \begin{margincap}
        \centering
        \caption{\\ Funktionsweise einer Laserstrahlquelle \\
            \cite{POP05,EIC10}}
        \includegraphics[width=0.8\textwidth]{Bilder_final/Prinzip_Laserquelle.png}
    \end{margincap}
    \caption*{}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Use `top` option for package `mcaption`. \usepackage[top]{mcaption}

Comment: awesome! That worked, thanks a lot! Post it as answer if you want, that why the solution is more visible :)

Comment: Your welcome. Thank you for your hint. I have added my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `top` option for package `mcaption`.

```
 \usepackage[top]{mcaption}
```

I have used `example-image-a` as a picture and disable font used in your code.
[image]